# ClearCase 8.0.x comes with Which IBM java version?

Tags: clearcase

I see Java 6 in some website and as this is not the current version of Java, there would be still be a perceived security risk around this.

So which IBM java version comes with ClearCase 8.0.x?

Comment: why I asked is, I see Java 6 in some website and as this is not the current version of Java, there would be still be a perceived security risk around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete sources of information are:

- "[ClearCase system requirement](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/clearcase#tab_othertab1)", and
- "[Rational ClearCase version 8.0.0.x Release Notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21504789)" and [8.0.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037036).
  (for instance, the 8.0.1.3 mentions that the IBM JRE has been updated with Java 6 Sr15)

The [supported JDK](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1316006977787&osPlatforms=Windows#sw-7) is

**IBM Runtime Environment, Java Technology Edition**: 6.0.9
The prerequisite *minimum* is 6.0.9.3 for ClearCase 8.0.1.